# How to pass the key for the mat-select option as param using @Input in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

I would like to show the mat-option's options values based on the string which was sent from parent to child component using @Input.

Please find the below code block

**cdropdown.component.ts**

```
@Componenet({
selector: 'mat-dropdown',
templateUrl: 'mat-dropdown.component.html',
styleUrls: ['mat-dropdown.componenet.css']
})
export class dropDownComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(){}

@Input() selectFormControl : FormControl;
@Input() options : Object[];
@Input() OptionValue: any;
}
```

**cdropdown.component.html**

```
<mat-select [formControl]="selectFormControl" [placeholder]="placeholder">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let  option of options" [value]="option">
    {{option.optionvalue}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

i am creating a common component for the mat-select .so i am passing the value for the option as list of object. The key "optionvalue" for the option may differs. so i would like to define what key should be used for the mat-option.

Now i have the {{option.optionvalue}}. i have to send the string 'optionvalue' from parent component using @Input. is it possible please advise.

**parentcomponent**

```
options : object[] = [
 {
  key:1,
  optionValue:data1
 },
 {
  key:2,
  optionValue:data2
 }
]
```

**parent html **

```
<mat-dropdown [options]= "options" ></mat-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the property to use for the option value via the parent component, you can use the following expression `{{option[optionValue]}}` in your template.

Pass the property string as follows:

`@Input() optionValue: string;`

Comment: i have tried as like above but drop down is shows as blank. please advise

Comment: Did you make sure the naming of the variable is correct? It is always spelled differently in your example. The input is `OptionValue`, in the template it is `optionvalue` and in your array it is `optionValue`. Maybe produce a stackblitz?

Comment: Its working now . issue was spelling mistake. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You could `@Input` the key name.

Parent

.html

`<mat-dropdown optionValue="optionvalue">`

Child

.html

```
...
    {{option[optionValue]}}
...
```

.ts

```
@Input() optionValue: string;
```

Comment: i have tried as like the above solution. but drop down is  shows as empty. please advise